# Displaying custom error on View on primary key violation with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want a custom error message to be displayed just as is the case for required, regex etc, but for primary key violation.

The check is done so as to never be able to insert a primary key. What do I put in else?

I don't want to use Ajax or `ViewBag/ViewState`, else I know how to do it that way. I want to display that error "This code already exists " on form post.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Code,Libelle")] Marque marque)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var codeExists = _context.Marque.Where(s => s.Code == marque.Code)
                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                                        .Code == marque.Code ? "yes" : "no";

        if (codeExists == "no")
        {
            _context.Add(marque);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    return View(marque);
}
```

Comment: The `codeExists` construction is unnecessarily obtuse. All you need is `var codeExists = await _context.Marque.AnyAsync(x => x.Code == marque.Code);`. Then just do `if (!codeExists)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a model error to object, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Code,Libelle")] Marque marque)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var codeExists = _context.Marque.Where(s => s.Code == marque.Code).FirstOrDefault().Code == marque.Code ? "yes" : "no";
        if (codeExists == "no")
        {
            _context.Add(marque);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
             ModelState.AddModelError("Error occurred", "Your custom error exception");
        }
    }
    return View(marque);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a web application and not web api - because this is not specified in your code.

In Asp.net core, you can configure Error handling middleware:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Then you can have Error controller as shown below, which returns view based on the exception type.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
    HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

    if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error is FileNotFoundException)
    {
        ExceptionMessage = "File error thrown";
    }
    if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Path == "/index")
    {
        ExceptionMessage += " from home page";
    }

     // Either show exception message on page or return different views based on conditions.
}
```

Hope this helps!

**TIP** - even if you have web APIs, you can choose to return business error codes form API to UI, and then UI can show appropriate error messages based on those codes.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guilherme.

Below is the code that works.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Code,Libelle")] Marque marque)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var codeExists = _context.Marque.Where(s => s.Code == marque.Code).FirstOrDefault().Code == marque.Code ? "yes" : "no";
        if (codeExists == "no")
        {
            _context.Add(marque);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Code","This code already exists");
        }
    }
    return View(marque);
}
```